# Threshold based weight pruning in keras/tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pruning

Is there a way to prune a Keras model based on a certain threshold? The method prune_low_magnitude() from the tensorflow-model-optimization toolkit only allows pruning based on a defined final sparsity (percentage of remaining weigths). Is there a function I am missing or do you know a workaround?